# Android app can't read external storage files

Tags: android, file

I'm creating an app for a private use only... it's not so important then, respect your time :P

What I want to make is an app that reads from a database and plays sounds. I've already made the database and I am able to play sound from res/raw folder. However, there are thousands of files to play and some new ones will be a part of the app and other will be deleted in the future. So, adding a simple file makes me to download the whole app (~1 GB) each time (or maybe I'm wrong?). Instead, I thought of reading an Excel file and playing sounds from SD card then. But I can't... as far as i know:

> Apps are not allowed to write (delete, modify ...) to external storage
>   except to their package-specific directories.

I put the files into the **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_package_folder/files** folder. I've read really many topics and nothing helped me.

```
Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState) //returns true
Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState) //returns false
```

I tried a few ways of creating new file object or playing the sound with the mediaplayer (as I've said before, there's no problem with playing res/raw files) but **file.exists** always returns false or sound doesn't play:

```
String filePath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/myfile.mp3"; //returns correct file path
File file = new File(filePath);
```

OR

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath(), "myfile.mp3");
```

OR

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/myfile.mp3"));
```

The minSdkVersion is set to 19 so I don't need that line in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have included that line and nothing changed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

I was also trying to do that with other file extensions. Also, the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025930/6556247) didn't help. My phone is Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime (SM-G530FZ), Android v. 5.0.2. Help, please! :)

Comment: whats your targetSdk?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: check my answer if it helps :)

Comment: Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253397/android-permisson-request-code-issue/37253779#37253779

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code @Nisarg, had to clean it a bit:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button readExcelButton;
static String TAG = "ExelLog";
MediaPlayer mpintro;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission checking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkPermission();
    }

    readExcelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readExcel);
    readExcelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.readExcel:
            String filePath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/p0000.mp3";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            file.setReadable(true);
            file.setWritable(true);

            if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ext storage not available or read only", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ext storage available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (file.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "File found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/p0000.mp3 - File not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}

private void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {//Can add more as per requirement

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                123);

    } else {

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)     {
                //Peform your task here if any
            } else {

                checkPermission();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

if your targetSdk is 23 than you have to check permissions like this for marshmallow and above devices

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    checkPermission();
}
else {
}


private void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {//Can add more as per requirement

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    123);

        } else {

        }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults)   
   {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123: {


 if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)     {
   //Peform your task here if any
    } else {

        checkPermission();
    }
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You mean "default" instead of "else" in that switch, I guess? No, nothing's changed ;(

Comment: @kuznikowski check edited answer sorry it was my mistake

Comment: Damn, I'm new here and need to ask a stupid question... that first IF has to be put in my onCreate void I guess? It returns false so the rest of code doesn't execute.

Comment: too long for a comment, I'll put it into an answer

Comment: @kuznikowski its fine what is the issue?

Comment: Well, i don't like using that Log.v, Log.i etc., my toasts tell me that Ext storage available but file doesn't exist. Your IF doesn't execute as I've stated before.

Comment: @kuznikowski you arent using marshmallow device than?

Comment: cmon, I know -,- erased IF and executed, didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You also have to have the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE; Either write or read is not enough when it comes to external storage, as you have to use both

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You can also read more about external data writing in the [declaration](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

The reason you cannot read is because you didn't add that permission. A good rule is if you **only need to read**, only use read permission. But if you **need to write** you need the write and the read permission

**EDIT:**

When loading the directory, try this:

```
file.setReadable(true);
file.setWritable(true);
```

Note: the value 'file' here is for the directory, not each separate file(all though that works fine too)

From the declaration:

> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage.

If I am correct that means the permission **has to be there** from API 19 and up, but not before API 19

Comment: API 19, I don't need it... but OK, I've checked it once again, added both WRITE and READ permissions, didn't help.

Comment: did you try file.setReadable and file.setWritable?

Comment: Well, what I've found there - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - "Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories"

EDIT:
Yes, setReadable and setWritable didn't help.

Comment: If you do not need to read externally(files from other apps saved publically) you could try this: http://pastebin.com/fTPT1JKi

Comment: Nah, dunno how to use it. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: call Saver.save with name, value(string) and context and call Saver.load and you see the suggestions for what suits the variable you are using. Also, in difference from external storage this form of saving is way safer

Answer (score 0):

```
 MyMediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(String.valueOf(Uri.fromFile(f))));
```

in this `MyMediaPlayer` is object of `MediaPlayer,||ly f` is object of file
in this we convert to uri first and then uri to string and finally string to uri.

I have done this because when we take the path of our choise it take `/// 3times /` but it is needed only 2 times thats why I have done this conversion which help me to take the desired file path.

try this my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Android 9 (API level 28) started to restrict which apps could make the files in their data directories on internal storage world-accessible to other apps. Apps that target Android 9 or higher cannot make the files in their data directories world-accessible. For further info you can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Incase you're targeting the API level 28 or higher, to solve your problem you can simply add some tags inside your **AndroidManifest.xml**. So it should have at least those ones:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="com.your.application">

   <!-- These three tags -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <!-- Add the tag android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in application -->
   <!-- Other tags has been omitted -->
   <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Now you can check if you are able to read and write:

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My app folder");

Log.d("Storage: can write", String.valueOf(root.canWrite()));
Log.d("Storage: can read", String.valueOf(root.canRead()));
```

The result of both logs should be TRUE.