# Downloading Files to storage/emulated/0/ throws open Failed permission denied error in Cordova only for Target Version 23

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to download file from server to ionic app using cordova-file transfer plugin, it is working fine for android target SDK 22, but when I change the target SDK to 23 and try it throws EACESS open failed {Permission denied} error.

Here is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Download Function is:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (fileEntry) {   
    var filepath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory  + attachment.attachment_name;
    console.log("filepath", filepath)
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    // console.log('FilePath ' + filepath);
    fileTransfer.download(data.URL, filepath,
       function (fileEntry) {  
             // console.log("download complete: " + fileEntry.toURL());
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("ErrorDownload: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    true,
    {});                        
 });
```

ERROR:

```
target":"file:///storage/emulated/0/ionic.png","http_status":200,"body":null,"exception":"/storage/emulated/0/ionic.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"
```

If I change targetSDK to 22 then file file will be downloaded to storage/sdcard/ path.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38226786/3117966) might help

Comment: You should check for permission before accessing it.

Comment: Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253397/android-permisson-request-code-issue/37253779#37253779

Comment: @Nisarg I am using ionic framework, its not possible to use your solution.

Comment: @Pradeep S try it buddy

Comment: I am having the same issue, however I am trying to upload a video captured on the phone to my remote server. It never asks for permission it just says permission denied. I also tried the localURL instead of fullPath and it still wont work.

Comment: @Fostah I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?