# Why does my File.mkdirs() always return false?

Tags: java, android, file, android-external-storage, mkdirs

I am following the code snippet given here in this guide. The following lines (particurly the last `if` block in the following lines) are presenting a problem:

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that **`return null;`** in the snippet above is always executed.

This means that `mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()` always returns false.

The question is why and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @Solace whats your targetSdk?

Comment: it returns false if the directory exists as well

Comment: @Solace if its 23 than [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38226786/3117966) this

Comment: Add run time permissions, it will help

Comment: please make sure you have written write permission in android manifest file

Comment: @Nisarg I had set `6.0` while creating the project but i have tried to run it on `4.4` emulator, and `4.1` real device. Minimum is `8`

Comment: @Nisarg But I DO have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions declared in Manifest. :s

Comment: @Nisarg That didn't help

Comment: @Blackbelt How can I check whether it exists or not?

Comment: @Solace Yes I was searching for that only, runtime permissions dont work here because you are running on 4.1 and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032360/3117966) it might be the case

Comment: @Nisarg But same is the case with Genymotion emulator (running 4.4) :s

Comment: Using `mediaStorageDir.exists()`, as you can see in the question.

Comment: @Solace Found anything ?

Comment: @Nisarg No. :( I added read permissions in addition to write permissions in android. I tried the runtime permissions method which you had suggested. I also tried replacing `mkdir` instead of `mkdirs`. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: @Solace Yup its strange, I saw many links nothing found particularly why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

do you have set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your Manifest file?

Comment: No, I just have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: You might need both. Give it a try.

Comment: you don't need both. You have write permission, the read permission is "built-in"